# Automatic LaTex document generation from Excel spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, latex

I have some data in an Excel file from which I have to generate a report. I repeat this task fairly regularly and am looking to automate it. I have a LaTeX project into which I usually just copy data by hand, export the necessary worksheets as pdfs and add them to my LaTeX project and compile with `pdflatex`.

It has occurred to me that there must be a way to automate this process. Is there an efficient way to export the data from Excel and into a LaTeX project, possibly a VBA script in excel could run the process? Also, it doesn't have to be LaTeX, I'm not all that experienced with MS Office's more advanced features is there some way akin to a mail merge that I could achieve this with? In some ways this might be better in case I have to pass the work on to someone who doesn't know LaTeX.

Comment: Short answer is yes, absolutely. But I think a sample input and desired sample output would make this question a lot more concrete and yield better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as was asked in the comments, some example of your requested input and output will help to give a better answer.

But to generate LaTeX from Excel is possible with this plugin [excel2latex](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/excel2latex/).

You could also have a look at it's source code, and modify it for your needs, because LaTeX is a plain text file.